# Perl JSON how to get value of key

Tags: json, perl

I have the following json output and i'm trying to get the value of enabled

```
{  
   "_id":"sensor1",
   "_returned":1,
   "_embedded":{  
      "rh:doc":[  
         {  
            "_id":{  },
            "enabled":"true"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have tried the following

```
foreach my $x ( @{$vsConfig}) {
    print $x;
}
```

I'm not sure why its not returning anything, isn't it a hash reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `$vsConfig` is a hash ref obtained after the json was decoded:

```
print $vsConfig->{_embedded}->{'rh:doc'}->[0]->{enabled}
```

The whole code, including the part that decodes the json:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw/decode_json/;

my $json = q|
{  
   "_id":"sensor1",
   "_returned":1,
   "_embedded":{  
      "rh:doc":[  
         {  
            "_id":{  },
            "enabled":"true"
         }
      ]
   }
}
|;

my $vsConfig = decode_json( $json );

print $vsConfig->{_embedded}->{'rh:doc'}->[0]->{enabled};
```

Comment: You can drop all of those arrows after the first one, as in print $vsConfig->{_embedded}{'rh:doc'}[0]{enabled}

Comment: I know, I use the arrows as a personal preference - they give me the impression that the code is more readable

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just want to know why you had to specify {0}?

Comment: @Deano Actually, it is [0], rh:doc is an array with one element.  You might want to loop through that array if you expect more than one element.